# Scaffolding A model with an attribute of type datetime creates a 10 years range in the form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date

For a simple rails application ( 1.86 /2.3.5) , lets say I run a simple scaffold

```
script/generate scaffold blog title:string content:text published:date
```

When I open up the new / edit view for the blog controller in index/new.html.erb , I see that the drop down enabler for date select has a date range of 2005 - 2015 , i.e 5 years +/-

I tried to change this default behavior by introducing this code

```
f.date_select :entered,
              :start_year => 1970,
              :end_year => 2020
```

Apparently this has no impact to the behavior mentioned above. How do I increase the date_select range which seems to be default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be ok. Except did you put it inside the `<%= %>` ?

**Edit:** Also i noticed that you say your scaffold has published column whereas your date_select refers to the entered column.

As in, `<%= f.date_select :published, :start_year => 1970, :end_year => 2020 %>`
If that doesn't work you can also try,

`<%= f.date_select :published, :start_year => Time.now.year - 40, :end_year => Time.now.year + 10 %>`

I tried it and it works for me. Cheers! :)